# In c#, my datagrid is not showing the rows

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid which I fill with a data set, several are done this way and they work, just one does not, why?

Code

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgServer" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 
    ondeletecommand="dataGrid1_DeleteCommand" 
    oneditcommand="dataGrid1_EditCommand" 
    OnSortCommand="dataGrid1_SortCommand">
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#C1D0EC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:EditCommandColumn  CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Editar" 
                    UpdateText="Update">
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:EditCommandColumn>
                <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Borrar"></asp:ButtonColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id"
                     Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Server" HeaderText="Servidor" 
                    SortExpression="Server" >
                </asp:BoundColumn>

        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Port" HeaderText="Puerto" SortExpression="Port"
                   ></asp:BoundColumn >
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="User" HeaderText="Usuario" SortExpression="User"
                   ></asp:BoundColumn >
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password"
                   ></asp:BoundColumn >
                   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PassAuten" HeaderText="PassAut" SortExpression="PassAut">
                   </asp:BoundColumn>



            </Columns>
            <EditItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0B63A2" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

How is done in every other and it works:

```
 public void LlenarDataGridServer()
    {

            //read = Con.executar_re("Select * from SMTP");
            //dataGrid1.DataSource = read.Tables[0];
            //dataGrid1.DataBind();
        DataSet verServer = Con.executar_re("select * from dbo.smtp");

        dgServer.DataSource = verServer.Tables[0];
        dgServer.DataBind();


    }
```

So whats up, this is killing me. Thanks.

Edit: Yes the table is set up, I can access the data from sql server and is 1 row which I plan to update.

2 Edit: The same lines are filling other DG like

```
 public void LlenarDatagridConsecutivos()
    {

        read = Con.executar_re("select * from TypeCConsecutiveDocument");
        dgConsecutivos.DataSource = read.Tables[0];
        dgConsecutivos.DataBind();

    }
```

And the Con.etc:

```
 public DataSet executar_re(string comando)
    {
        try
        {

            connnection01.Open();

            SqlCommand command01 = new SqlCommand();

            command01.CommandText = comando;
            command01.Connection = connnection01;

            SqlDataReader re01 = command01.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            DataSet ds = Convert(re01);

            re01.Close();
            connnection01.Close();
            return ds;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqle)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sqle.ToString());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            return ds;

        }
```

Comment: My guess is the `DataSet` coming back from the call to `Con.executar_re("select * from dbo.smtp");` is `null`, which does not cause the `dgServer.DataSource` line to blow up, but it just renders no rows. Check with the debugger to see if the `DataSet` is null.

Comment: Well is not null, is empty I have no idea why

Comment: To the grid, empty and null are the same, nothing for it to display.

Comment: Post the code for `Con.executar_re("select * from dbo.smtp");`.

Comment: Is posted on the question (:

Comment: Are you sure there are no Exceptions thrown ? Also what is the Convert method doing ?

Comment: Is an exception happening? Since you are newing up a `DataSet` object in the exception handler, my guess is an exception is happening being written to the debugger and not seen by you, because you said the `DataSet` comes back empty, which is what a newly created `DataSet` is; empty that is. Step through the code and see if/what exception happens.

Comment: Ok, the covert is transforming a SqlReader into a DS.

Comment: Have you tryed something like that to return directly a DataSet : SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command01); DataSet ds = new DataSet();da.Fill(ds); return ds;

Comment: Nope, no exception is thrown, I'm stumped

Comment: Have you tryed the piece of code I gave you to directly get a DataSet without converting anything ?

Comment: Your code Guigui did not help, now this specific grid is not showing anything at all, previously is was no record, now is completely blank, the others are normal ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, it was something really strange:

1. I change the table name from smtp to mailServer
2. I put the column name's in [name]
3. I got rid of the DG and put it in a label which changes

I think is more likely to be 1, 2.

Something funny is going on with some name :o

Edited: to look better

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is going on in that Convert method, but, see this link about how to use a SqlDataReader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Should be something like this:

```
List<IDataRecord> records = new List<IDataRecord>();
while(re01.Read())
{
    //add record to list
    records.Add((IDataRecord)re01);
}
//records now has your list of data.
re01.close();
```

Comment: The convert is doing pretty much the same, I could add it but I don't want to clutter up

Comment: Then I would start looking into what others have pointed out, and start figuring out if you have an exception being thrown. Given that you aren't getting a null back, an exception is the most likely culprit, seeing as how you are newing up a dataset in the handler.